# status.setComplete() not clearing the session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am trying to clear a session. Below is a little sample code I wrote to check with `SessionStatus`.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value={"sessAttr1","sessAttr2","sessAttr3"})
public class SessionController {    
@RequestMapping(value="index")
public ModelAndView populateSession(){      
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("home");
    modelView.addObject("sessAttr1","This value is added in a session 1");
    modelView.addObject("sessAttr2","This value is added in a session 2");
    modelView.addObject("sessAttr3","This value is added in a session 3");
    return modelView;
}

@RequestMapping(value="home1")
public String populateHomeSession(SessionStatus status){
    status.setComplete();
    return "home1";
}
}
```

When `home1` screen is displayed, I can still see the session objects not getting cleared. If I try this: `${sessAttr1 }` then I can read the session values in `home1` screen.

Please clarify why is it not working.

**EDIT**

I an using `<a href="home1">Next</a>` to navigate from one screen to another. Does it have something to do with this isse I am facing?

Comment: use session.invalidate()

Comment: Thats fine...I can use `removeAttribute` as well or some other options that I use in a simple Servlet Application but my question is why is the above example not working. Please let me know on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setComplete` is used to mark a session attribute as not needed *after* the request has been processed by the controller: It does not immediately modify the session, and it overall sounds like it's a poor fit for your use case.  It's intended to be used in a situation like a POST where the data is intended to be used during the present request, but should not be used in the future.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/108339-problem-with-sessionattribute-and-sessionstatus

Comment: As you said: `It does not immediately modify the session` Iwant to know when is actually the session gets modified?

Comment: I answered the question you asked...if you have a different question you should modify the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [invalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29)

```
@RequestMapping(value="home1")
public String populateHomeSession(HttpservletRequest request){

HttpSession session=request.getSession();
session.invalidate();

    return "home1";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet but thats not something that I want. I can use `removeAttribute` as well or some other options that I use in a simple Servlet Application but my question is why is the above example not working. Please let me know on this.

Comment: Another thing I missed out: In my jsp screens, I an using `<a href="home1">Next</a>` to navigate from one screen to another. Does it have something to do with this isse I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

status.setComplete(); remove sessionatribute after render.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.