# Spring MVC, updating Model Map on form post still shows old info

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model

Please bear with my limited knowledge of spring mvc. 
I'm trying to refresh a view with updated model info after a POST request. The new info appears on the view, as well as the old version, which completely messes up the view.

Here is my controller code. If you see something that isn't correct please let me know, thanks in advance!

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"Game"})
public class SimpleController {

    @Autowired
    private SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver;

    private LoginValidator loginValidator;
    private GameValidator gameValidator;

    @Autowired
    public void setLoginValidator(LoginValidator loginValidator) {
        this.loginValidator = loginValidator;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setGameValidator(GameValidator gameValidator) {
        this.gameValidator = gameValidator;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView init(ModelMap model) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/login.jsp");
        LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
        model.addAttribute("LoginBean", loginBean);
        model.addAttribute("game", new Game());

        model.addAttribute("ENGLISH", Language.ENGLISH);
        model.addAttribute("SPANISH", Language.SPANISH);

        mav.addObject("LoginBean", loginBean);
        return mav;

    }

    @RequestMapping (value="/processLogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @ModelAttribute("loginBean") LoginBean loginBean, 
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {


        this.loginValidator.validate(loginBean, result);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:/login.htm";
        }

        Game game = new Game();     

        if (loginBean.getLanguage() == Language.ENGLISH) {          
            localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("EN"));
        }
        else{
            localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("ES"));
        }

        loginBean.setDictionary(FileLoader.loadDictionary(loginBean.getLanguage()));        

        game.setPlayer(loginBean.getPlayer());
        game.setLanguage(loginBean.getLanguage());
        game.setDictionary(loginBean.getDictionary());
        game.setSelectedWord(game.getRandomWord(game.getDictionary()));


        model.addAttribute("Game", game); 
        request.getSession().setAttribute("game", game);

        System.out.println(game.getSelectedWord());

        return "redirect:/index.htm";   
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView play(HttpServletRequest request,
            @ModelAttribute("game") Game game, ModelMap model){         

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/index.jsp");

        if(request.getSession().getAttribute("game") != null) {
            game = (Game)request.getSession().getAttribute("game");
            mav.addObject("game", game);        
        } else {
            System.out.println("nothing received");
        }

        request.getSession().setAttribute("game", game);

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping (value="/guessLetter", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView guessLetter (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
            @ModelAttribute("game") Game game, @RequestParam("guess") String guess,
            SessionStatus status, ModelMap model) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/index.jsp");

        if(request.getSession().getAttribute("game") != null) {
            game = (Game)request.getSession().getAttribute("game");

            game.guessLetter(guess);

        } else {
            System.out.println("no guess!");
        }


        //model.replace("game", game); tried this, but didn't work
        System.out.println(model.entrySet());
        model.addAttribute("Game", game);
        //request.getSession().setAttribute("game", game);  

        mav.addObject("game", game);
        status.setComplete();

        return mav;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't fully understand SessionStatus methods. This answer has been really helpful   https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342814/2438413

Below is my working controller in case anyone wants it for reference:

```
@RequestMapping (value="/guessLetter", method=RequestMethod.POST)  
        public ModelAndView guessLetter (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
                @ModelAttribute("game") Game game, @RequestParam("guess") String guess,
                SessionStatus status, ModelMap model, BindingResult result) {
            System.out.println(guess);

            this.letterValidator.validate(game, result);

            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return new ModelAndView("/views/index.jsp");
            }    

            request.getSession().setAttribute("game", game);        
            game.guessLetter(guess);        

            System.out.println(game.getGuessList());

            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:index.htm");

            mav.addObject("game", game);
            model.addAttribute("game", game);
            return mav;
        }
```